# Post increment in operator overloading in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, post-increment

This is my post increment operator overloading declaration.

```
loc loc::operator++(int x)
{
    loc tmp=*this;
    longitude++;
    latitude++;
    retrun tmp;
}
```

My class constructor

```
loc(int lg, int lt) 
{
   longitude = lg;
   latitude = lt;
}
```

In main function, I have coded like below

```
int main()
{
    loc ob1(10,5);
    ob1++;
}
```

While compiling this , i am getting the below error

> opover.cpp:56:5: error: prototype for ‘loc loc::operator++(int)’ does
>   not match any in class ‘loc’ 
>     opover.cpp:49:5: error: candidate is: loc
>   loc::operator++() opover.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   opover.cpp:69:4: error: no ‘operator++(int)’ declared for postfix ‘++’

Comment: You fail to show the class declaration

Comment: Show us your class declaration? is `loc::operator++(int x)` declared in opover.h?

Answer (score 4):

Fix your class declaration from

```
class loc
{
    // ...
    loc operator++();
}
```

to

```
class loc
{
    // ...
    loc operator++(int);
}
```

[**Edit** removed misguided remarks about returning by value. Returning by value is *of course* the usual semantics for postfix operator++]

Comment: Why should we have parameter in `operator++` function? This is unary operation.. we don't have to pass anything inside

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov: I don't think we have to. You'd have to ask the OP what he wants to achieve. Regardless, the prototypes should match and I don't think the C++ specs forbid a parameter list. There just won't be a very useful way to invoke the operator except by calling `obj.operator++(42)`. Fixing my recommendation though, since you are right, this smells like a mistake

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov the parameter is to distinguish between post- and prefix increment.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong.. apologies. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading is explained overloading. without input parqams we have prefix overloading `++x`, with `int` as function params we have postfix overloading `x++`, so this is just to differentiate prefix and postfix.. sorry for making mistake

Comment: @Anders yes, just realized that

Comment: *Returning copies from `operator++` **is** the usual semantics* if you are implementing post-increment rather than preincrement. What you suggest is implementing a *different* operator that has different semantics

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas and @Anders: oops. Yeah, I confused by a two-step thinko (starting with me adding `&` to the return type , which was my mistake) **Fixed**

Answer (score 3):

you should have two versions of `++`:

```
loc& loc::operator++() //prefix increment (++x)
{
    longitude++;
    latitude++;
    return *this;
} 

loc loc::operator++(int) //postfix increment (x++)
{
    loc tmp(longtitude, langtitude);
    operator++();
    return tmp;
}
```

And, of course, both functions should be defined in class prototype:

```
loc& operator++();
loc operator++(int);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare the overloaded operator in your class definition.

Your class should look something like this:

```
class loc{
public:
    loc(int, int);
    loc operator++(int);
    // whatever else
}
```

** edit **

After reading the comments, I noticed that in your error message it shows that you declared `loc operator++()`, so just fix that.

Comment: not entirely true. he didn't declare the right signature, though